# How To Replace SearchDisplayController (Deprecated in IOS 8) by UIsearchController method

Tags: uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm obviously still new to Xcode. So `SeacrhDisplayController` is deprecated in iOS 8 and i don't know how to implement `UIsearchController` on tableview.

I have googled about it, but i don't see any particular or clear tutorials for this.

Here is my code for `SearchDisplayController`:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
    shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
    {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                                   scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                          objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                         selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

        return YES;
    }


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [categories count];
    }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FirstTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else  {
        cell.textLabel.text = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[thumbnails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];


    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"showArrayDetail" sender: self];
    }
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showArrayDetail"]) {
        SecondViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
            indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.categoryName = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView1 indexPathForSelectedRow];
            destViewController.categoryName = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I know this post is old but I was facing the same issue and I have found the following tutorials, much easier than Apple's example:

1. http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift
2. http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2015/02/16/updating-to-the-ios-8-search-controller.html

Choose what is more suitable for your need and have a happy coding!

Cheers,

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue i follow this steps:

**Step 1:** 
Add the `UISearchResultsUpdating` at your .h file

**Step 2:**
Create Property of `UISearchController`

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISearchController *searchController
```

**Step 3:**
Add the code at viewDidLoad()

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     NSLog(@"viewDidLoad Starts");
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
     self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
     self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false;
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

**Step 4:**
Impliment your Filter Stuff at `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
     // do your Filter code and reload tableView
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Step 5:** change your codition at `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
if (self.searchController.isActive) {
        return [searchResults count];

    } else {
        return [categories count];
    }
```

**Step 6:** Now just `run and check`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the sample code "Table Search with UISearchController (Obj-C and Swift)" on the Apple Developer site?

Comment: The problem is that this solution requires iOS 8 and my app still supports iOS 7. Is there some solution working for all systems, at least until I drop iOS 7?